# Db restructure due to performance issue

Tags: sql, database

Currently I have arround 250 clients with their 5 years datas and the tables structure were splited up based on their years (Eg),A client named as **XX**.
**T00_XX_2011**,**T00_XX_2012**,**T00_XX_2013**,**T00_XX_2014** each table contains 220 column with more or less 10 millions records in which 12 column already has indexes

The issue was for a single select query it get arround 5 to 10 min Can anyone help to tweek the performance

Comment: The question is quite broad as currently stated, what type of queries do you run on that tables? Also, you should put a sample of the table structure (not all columns but at least the primary key and the indexed columns)

Comment: I would say:  Without knowing anything about the database you are using or the queries being run, no one can help you.